# Function that checks if User has inputted something

Tags: javascript, function, require, required

I am having some difficulties on how to add a function. Could someone show me how I can add a function that will show a pop up message saying "name / password field empty" 
the problem here is if I click log in, while the input fields are empty, it still says user logged in? even though they were empty? I cannot use any php functions.

```
   <html>
 <head>
<title>Week 9 Q&A Session - Form Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<!--Registration form -->
<div>
    <h1>Registration</h1>
    <form onsubmit="registerUser()">
<input type="text" name="username" value="" id="name" required>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</div> 

<!-- Login form -->
<div>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="loginName">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="loginPassword">
    <button onclick="checkLogin()">Submit</button>
    <p id="LoginResult">Not logged in.</p>
</div> 

<!-- Rankings table will be inserted here -->
<div id="RankingsTable"></div>

<script>

    /* Does some basic checking of user data then stores
        user data in localStorage */
    function registerUser(){
        //Extract the name and password that the user has entered
        var nameInput = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var pwdInput = document.getElementById("password").value; 

        //Check that the name and password are not empty
        if(nameInput !== "" && pwdInput !== ""){
            //Create a JavaScript object to hold the user data.
            var usrObj = {};

            //Add user entered data to object
            usrObj.username = nameInput;
            usrObj.password = pwdInput;

            //Add a score field to object to support rankings table
            usrObj.topscore = 0;

            //Store a string version of the object in local storage.
            localStorage[nameInput] = JSON.stringify(usrObj);
        }
    }


    /* Checks that the username and password match the user name and password of a 
        registered user and provides feedback to user. */
    function checkLogin(){
        //Get a reference to the div where we will display the login result
        var loginResult = document.getElementById("LoginResult");

        //Extract the name and password that the user has entered
        var nameInput = document.getElementById("loginName").value;
        var pwdInput = document.getElementById("loginPassword").value; 

        //Output for debugging
        console.log("Login name: " + nameInput+ "; Login password" + pwdInput);

        //Check to see if we have data stored for this user
        if(localStorage[nameInput] === undefined){
            //No user found - provide feedback to user.
            loginResult.innerHTML = "User name incorrect";
            return;
        }

        //Check password
        //Get object that is stored for the user name.
        var usrObj = JSON.parse(localStorage[nameInput]);

        //Compare the entered password with the stored password
        if(pwdInput !== usrObj.password){
            //Incorrect password - provide feedback to user
            loginResult.innerHTML = "Password incorrect";
            return;
        }

        //If we have got this far, the username and password are correct

        //Record the user that has logged in using local storage.
        localStorage.loggedInUser = nameInput;

        //Provide feedback to user - you could also provide a logout button - see the example in my slides.
        loginResult.innerHTML = "User logged in.";
    }


    /* This function is called when a logged in user 
        plays the game and gets a score */
    function updateScore(newScore){
        //Get the JavaScript object that holds the data for the logged in user
        var usrObj = JSON.parse(localStorage[localStorage.loggedInUser]);

        //Update the user object with the new top score
        /* NOTE YOU NEED TO CHANGE THIS CODE TO CHECK TO SEE IF THE NEW SCORE
            IS GREATER THAN THE OLD SCORE */
        usrObj.topscore = newScore;

        //Put the user data back into local storage.
        localStorage[localStorage.loggedInUser] = JSON.stringify(usrObj);
    }


    /* Loads the rankings table.
        This function should be called when the page containing the rankings table loads */
    function showRankingsTable(){
        //Get a reference to the div that will hold the rankings table.
        var rankingDiv = document.getElementById("RankingsTable");

        //Create a variable that will hold the HTML for the rankings table
        var htmlStr = "";

        //Add a heading 
        htmlStr += "<h1>Rankings Table</h1>";

        //Add the table tag
        htmlStr += "<table>";

        //Work through all of the keys in local storage
        for(var key in localStorage) {
            //All of the keys should point to user data except loggedInUser
            if(key !== "loggedInUser"){
                //Extract object containing user data

                //Extract user name and top score
                htmlStr += "David";
                //Add a table row to the HTML string.
            }
        }

        //Finish off the table
        htmlStr += "</table>";

        //Add the table to the page.

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Instead of the popup you can show the error message below the respective text filed with red color.

Comment: You can also use html5 validations like "required" in input tag

Comment: I tried that but it's not working. can you try the code and tell me if it works for you?

Comment: What you have tried, html5 validations? Check also your browser version

Comment: can you show me what the working code would look like

Comment: @NatalieMcKnight SO is not a code writing service. We're here to help you fix your work but please do not ask people to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

To make an input field required, you should

- Wrap your form fields in an actual `<form>`
- Set your `<button>` is a "submit" type
- Trigger your function on the form `onsubmit` event instead of on the button's `onclick` event
- Then simply set a `required` attribute on the HTML element

Example

```
<form onsubmit="registerUser()">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="name" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This works because when a form is submitted (by a true submit button), the form first checks if all the field validators have been satisfied. If a `required` field is not filled, the form will not submit. So only when the form is fully valid will your `registerUser()` function get called because only then will the `submit` event fire.

Comment: can you apply it to my code please? I just tried it but it's not working for me

Comment: @NatalieMcKnight I've got a code example that demonstrates it in my answer that's based off your code.

Comment: I updated my code, take a look. it's still not working for me :/

Comment: @NatalieMcKnight can you be more specific about what isn't working.

Comment: well, I did what you told me with the forms, but if you try my code you will see that it still says 'logged in' even if the fields are empty

Comment: @NatalieMcKnight the example I gave was for the registration, you need to perform the same steps on your login form.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to your code. `checkLogin()` function. What it does is check if either of the fields is empty or not. If its empty then changes the text to "Please fill the fields". Also its not good practice to not end with the `</ body>` tag even though most browsers do that for you.

```js
if(nameInput.length === 0 || pwdInput.length == 0)
{
    loginResult.innerHTML = "Please fill the fields.";
    return;
}
```

Here I have just added that part to your existing code.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Week 9 Q&A Session - Form Demo</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!--Registration form -->
    <div>
        <h1>Registration</h1>
        <form onsubmit="registerUser()">
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="name" required>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div> 

    <!-- Login form -->
    <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="loginName">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="loginPassword">
        <button onclick="checkLogin()">Submit</button>
        <p id="LoginResult">Not logged in.</p>
    </div> 

    <!-- Rankings table will be inserted here -->
    <div id="RankingsTable"></div>

    <script>

        /* Does some basic checking of user data then stores
        user data in localStorage */
        function registerUser(){
            //Extract the name and password that the user has entered
            var nameInput = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var pwdInput = document.getElementById("password").value; 

            //Check that the name and password are not empty
            if(nameInput !== "" && pwdInput !== ""){
                //Create a JavaScript object to hold the user data.
                var usrObj = {};

                //Add user entered data to object
                usrObj.username = nameInput;
                usrObj.password = pwdInput;

                //Add a score field to object to support rankings table
                usrObj.topscore = 0;

                //Store a string version of the object in local storage.
                localStorage[nameInput] = JSON.stringify(usrObj);
            }
        }


        /* Checks that the username and password match the user name and password of a 
        registered user and provides feedback to user. */
        function checkLogin(){
            //Get a reference to the div where we will display the login result
            var loginResult = document.getElementById("LoginResult");

            //Extract the name and password that the user has entered
            var nameInput = document.getElementById("loginName").value;
            var pwdInput = document.getElementById("loginPassword").value; 

            //Output for debugging
            console.log("Login name: " + nameInput+ "; Login password" + pwdInput);
            if(nameInput.length === 0 || pwdInput.length == 0)
            {
                loginResult.innerHTML = "Please fill the fields.";
                return;
            }
            //Check to see if we have data stored for this user
            if(localStorage[nameInput] === undefined){
                //No user found - provide feedback to user.
                loginResult.innerHTML = "User name incorrect";
                return;
            }

            //Check password
            //Get object that is stored for the user name.
            var usrObj = JSON.parse(localStorage[nameInput]);

            //Compare the entered password with the stored password
            if(pwdInput !== usrObj.password){
            //Incorrect password - provide feedback to user
            loginResult.innerHTML = "Password incorrect";
            return;
        }

        //If we have got this far, the username and password are correct

        //Record the user that has logged in using local storage.
        localStorage.loggedInUser = nameInput;

        //Provide feedback to user - you could also provide a logout button - see the example in my slides.
        loginResult.innerHTML = "User logged in.";
        }


        /* This function is called when a logged in user 
        plays the game and gets a score */
        function updateScore(newScore){
            //Get the JavaScript object that holds the data for the logged in user
            var usrObj = JSON.parse(localStorage[localStorage.loggedInUser]);

            //Update the user object with the new top score
            /* NOTE YOU NEED TO CHANGE THIS CODE TO CHECK TO SEE IF THE NEW SCORE
            IS GREATER THAN THE OLD SCORE */
            usrObj.topscore = newScore;

            //Put the user data back into local storage.
            localStorage[localStorage.loggedInUser] = JSON.stringify(usrObj);
        }


        /* Loads the rankings table.
        This function should be called when the page containing the rankings table loads */
        function showRankingsTable(){
            //Get a reference to the div that will hold the rankings table.
            var rankingDiv = document.getElementById("RankingsTable");

            //Create a variable that will hold the HTML for the rankings table
            var htmlStr = "";

            //Add a heading 
            htmlStr += "<h1>Rankings Table</h1>";

            //Add the table tag
            htmlStr += "<table>";

            //Work through all of the keys in local storage
            for(var key in localStorage) {
                //All of the keys should point to user data except loggedInUser
                if(key !== "loggedInUser"){
                //Extract object containing user data

                //Extract user name and top score
                htmlStr += "David";
                //Add a table row to the HTML string.
                }
            }

            //Finish off the table
            htmlStr += "</table>";

            //Add the table to the page.

        }

    </script>
    
</body>
```